# Open Tkinter graphic form of another py file (no file, only graphic form)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

I have a main file, with a Tkinter graphic form (the classic window), called for example `A.py` and `main=Tk()`. Also how can I recall the B.py file if it is in a subfolder of the main project?

By clicking, for example, on an item in the bar menu such as "Open form B", how can I open the graphic form (classic window) of the `B.py? **IMPORTANT: without the output console, but only the graphic form**
P.S: if please don't use "self". thanks

FILE A.PY: MAIN

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

main=Tk()
main.title("xxxxxx")
main.geometry("750x750")
main.configure(bg='#282828')

#Bar Menù (no need to write all the code of bar menu)
filemenu.add_command (label = 'Open form B', command = ????)
```

FILE B.PY: SECONDARY

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

secondary=Tk()
secondary.title("yyyyyyy")
secondary.geometry("750x750")
secondary.configure(bg='#282828')
```

**EDIT (code updated, but i don't know if that's correct):**

FILE A.PY: MAIN

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from b import *

main=Tk()
main.title("xxxxxx")
main.geometry("750x750")
main.configure(bg='#282828')

#Bar Menù (no need to write all the code of bar menu)
filemenu.add_command (label = 'Open form B', command = b.draw_graph)
```

FILE B.PY: SECONDARY

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from b import *

def draw_graph():
    secondary=Toplevel("home/mypc/Destkop/Folder1/Folder2/B.py/secondary)
    secondary.title("yyyyyyy")
    secondary.geometry("750x750")
    secondary.configure(bg='#282828')
```

**UPLOAD 2 (only B.py):**

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

def draw_graph():
    global secondary=Toplevel()
    secondary.title("yyyyyyy")
    secondary.geometry("750x750")
    secondary.configure(bg='#282828')

#combobox
comboboxx=["xxxxxx", "xxxxx"]
combobox=ttk.Combobox(secondary, width=19)
combobox.place(x=6, y=12)
combobox.config(values=comboboxx)
combobox.set("Scegli")

# I only wrote a small part of the code, showing the combobox.
# But the code is very long. I would not like to put everything 
# in the function (if that is possible)
```

Error: combobox=ttk.Combobox(secondary, width=19)
NameError: name 'secondary' is not defined

Comment: By "graphic form" exactly do you mean window? The recommended why to open additional windows in `tkinter` is to create [`Toplevel`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/toplevel.html) widgets, **not** call `Tk()` multiple times.

Comment: @martineau Yes, that's right, I mean the classic window. Could you show me the answer please? I am new to Python. Thanks :)

Comment: if you will keep code in functions then you can decide when run them after `importing`. And functions could get `parent` as argument so when you import then you could use `Toplevel()` as `parent`, and when you run code directly then you could use `Tk()` as `parent`

Comment: if you want better answer then you have to create better question - don't expect that we will write all code for you. You could put minimal working code which we could simply copy and modify to create solution.

Comment: @furas Split the answer into two comments. Of course you're right. But being a very simple question, I thought the data I provided was enough, for example main = Tk (). Did I also have to write main.title ("title"), main.geometry ("750x750") and main.configure (bg = '# 282828')? Same for the second window? They are useless. I simply wrote the necessary data, ie main.title ("title") for the first window and secondary = Tk () for the second window, adding the names of the py files as well.

Comment: @furas Anyway a curiosity please, maybe you explained it to me above, but I didn't understand very well, forgive me: if I would like to open another window, can I directly open the name of the form secondary = Tk () without specifying def second? Is it mandatory to insert the function? In label = "Open A1", command = lambda: self.app.second (self.root)), so how should I write? (possibly without self and without connecting to the function). Thanks :)

Comment: first in `b.py` you should keep code in functions - ie. `draw_graph()` - and then you can `import b` and use `command=b.draw_graph`. In original question you didn't show code so we couldn't see if you have code in function or not - and it can't makes problem or not.

Comment: `Tk()` should be used only to create main window - other windows should be created with `Toplevel()` instead of `Tk()` - and code should use only one `mainloop()` - second `mainloop`  can make conflict and it may not display some widgets. `title` and `geometry` is not important. Important are widgets which you use in code.

Comment: @furas I got it. Anyway I added and modified the code thanks to your kind reply. Can you see if it's okay? If there is something to add or correct, can you write it to me in a reply (pasting my code) please? So I vote for you :) However, if the b.py file is in a subfolder (for example project / folder2), but the a.py file is in the main project folder, do you need to specify the path? Thanks

Comment: it is not OK. second window should use `Toplevel()` instead of `Tk()`

Comment: if module is in subfolder then you can try `import subfolder.b` but sometimes it may need to add current folder to list `sys.path`

Comment: don't change original code in question - now all my coments (and other answers) don't fit to your code and all comments seem totally useless. Better append new code with modifications (you can also add line `"EDIT:"` to show that it is modification)

Comment: @furas Ah OK. I'm sorry. I did not know. I had written the comment and edited the code before your comment. I have added EDIT. Anyway, how is the code going now? I didn't get it right for the subfolder. Considering that the code is now almost finished, can you copy and paste it completely and make corrections to the subfolder and possibly if I have something wrong please? So I vote for you as an answer. Thank you

Comment: I don't understand why you use `Toplevel("text-with-path")` . It has to be only `Toplevel()`

Comment: you should put original code `b.py` without `def draw_graph():` and below  add `EDIT:` with new `b.py` which has `def draw_graph():` Maybe visit some other questions and see how people write questions and answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code in `b.py` you should keep in functions to control when to run it

**b.py**

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
# in file `b.py` you don't need `import b` nor `from b import *` 


def draw_graph():
    win = tk.Toplevel()
    label = tk.Label(win, text="GRAPH")
    label.pack()
```

and then you can `import b` and assing `command=b.draw_graph`

**main.py**

(I use `Button` to create minimal working code - so everyone can simply copy and run it)

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
import b  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()  # PEP8: spaces around `=` when assigning to variable
    
    # ... code ...
    
    #filemenu.add_command(label='Open form A1', command=b.draw_graph)  # PEP8: `=` without spaces when assigning arguments
    # to use `b.draw_graph` you have to use `import b`, not `from b import *`
    
    button = tk.Button(root, text="Open form A1", command=b.draw_graph)
    button.pack() 
    
    root.mainloop()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':    
    main()
```

If you would use

```
from b import *
```

then you would have to use `command=draw_graph` instead of `command=b.draw_graph`

---

If you have `b.py` in subfolder with name `other` then you can do

```
from other import b
```

and still use `command=b.draw_graph`

or

```
import other.b
```

and then you has to use `command=other.b.draw_graph`

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008)

---

**EDIT:**

I already wrote how to use code from subfolder but I repeat

if you have `Folder1/main.py` and `Folder1/Folder2/B.py` then in `main.py` you need only

```
from Folder2 import B

command=B.draw_graph
```

or

```
import Folder2.B

command=Folder2.B.draw_graph
```

(if file has upper case name `B` then module has also upper case name `B`)

It should work without adding folder to `sys.path` and without adding file `Folder2/__init__.py`

If you will have `Folde1/main.py` and `Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/B.py` then you need

```
from Folder2.Folder3 import B

command=B.draw_graph
```

or

```
import Folder2.Folder3.B

command=Folder2.Folder3.B.draw_graph
```

---

Eventually you can add current folder to `sys.path` before import

```
import os
import sys

BASE_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
sys.path.append(BASE_DIR)

from Folder2 import B
#import Folder2.B
```

and it will work also when you run code from different folder
(different `Current Working Directory` - check `print(os.getcwd())`)

For example

```
cd ..
python Folder1/main.py
```

or

```
cd /
python /home/mypc/Destkop/Folder1/main.py
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Thankssssss :) Beautiful answer. But you forgot to write how to load B.py if it is in a subfolder. For example, if main.py is in home / mypc / Destkop / Folder1 and B.py is in home / mypc / Destkop / Folder1 / Folder2 / B.py. How can I get this? However, tomorrow I rewrite the question well. I write the old initial code and then separately add UPLOAD 1, so the readers understand. Then of course I vote for your kind response :) I am grateful if you change your answer for the subfolder problem. Thanks, see you tomorrow

Comment: I already wrote it - `from Folder2 import B` or `import Folder2.B` - but I used name `other` . I only didn't show how to add `Folder1` to `sys.path` to make sure it finds `Folder2` when you will run code from different folder than `Folder1` - ie `python Folder1/main.py` instead of `python main.py`

Comment: You wrote me a beautiful answer. It looks like a book. Good! Sincere congratulations! Now I am editing my question as we said yesterday. A few minutes. However I get an error. I did as you said, but I get this: import b ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'b'. I have tried with both import b and from b import *. I also changed command = b.draw_graph or even command = draw_graph. I did exactly as you wrote me, both in A.py and B.py. Why this error? Thank you

Comment: if you have filename `B.py` with upper case `B` then you have to `import B` with upper case `B` - I also wrote it in answer.

Comment: Yes, I divide the answer into 2 parts because it is too long. I read. Aaaaaa, I thought b was an external library. Instead would that be my file name? Here, it seemed strange. For example if my file instead of B.py was called ExampleForm2, I would have to import import ExampleForm2 and then write command = ExampleForm2.draw_graph. Ok.

Comment: However I tried, I get an error that: combobox_city = ttk.Combobox (win, width = 19) NameError: name 'win' is not defined. It didn't come out before, it does come out now that I put win = tk.Toplevel () inside def draw_graph () (as you kindly showed me). So it turns out not definvo win. I copy and paste win = tk.Toplevel () out of the def? Or out I write win = Tk ()?

Comment: now you have different proble - so import works. `win` is local variable which doesn't exists outside function - inside function you would need use `global win` to inform function that you want to create global variable `win`. Or you should create `Combobox(win, ...)` inside the same function as you create `win = tk.Toplevel()`

Comment: Global, right, I hadn't thought about it. I did this, but there is an error (syntax): def draw_graph (): global win = tk.Toplevel() I get the error when I write global

Comment: it has to be only `global win` and in other line as before `win = tk.Toplevel()`

Comment: I tried to write global win, only global win. I tried inside the function first (in the previous line a = tk.Toplevel ()), then I also tried outside the function (above the function, but outside). It gives me the same error NameError: name 'win' is not defined

Comment: why do you use `a =  tk.Toplevel ()` instead of `win = tk.Toplevel ()`. Did you put `Combobox(win, ...)` in function? if you have it outside function then it executed when you import file - so it is executed before you create `win = ...` . As I said at the beginning - you have to keep **ALL CODE** in functions. And `Combobox(win, ...)` has to be after `win = ...` BTW: in my code I create `Label(win,...)` and I do it inside `draw_graph`, after `win = ...` - it can't be outside `draw_graph`

Comment: I wrote wrong (I'm using Google translate). Obviously a win = tk.Toplevel (), not a =. The script code is very very long. Do I need to insert it in the function? Can I insert only win = tk.Toplevel (), win.title ("xxx"), win.geometry ("800x600") and win.configure (bg = '# 282828') into the function? I updated my application with an UPLOAD 2 from B.PY only. Can you tell me how I should do it please? Don't get mad, but I'm not understanding (also Google translator's fault) Thank you

Comment: as I said - **ALL CODE** has to be inside function (except `import`). If you keep code outside function then it will run it automatically when you import file but you need to run this code only when you click button in `main.py`

Comment: PERFECT. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Toplevel() function

1. make the first file as you want like name and write this code (a.py for exemple)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from b import *

class app:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.menu_bar()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def menu_bar(self):
        self.app = app1()
        self.menubar = Menu(self.root)
        self.filemenu = Menu(self.menubar, tearoff=0)
        self.filemenu.add_command(
            label="Open A1", command=lambda: self.app.second(self.root))
        self.filemenu.add_separator()
        self.filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.root.quit())
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=self.filemenu)
        self.root.config(menu=self.menubar)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app(Tk())
```

---

2. and in the second file make sure that he name as you write in a.py(from filename import *) (b.py for the exemple) and write like this

```
class app1:
    def second(self, root):
        self.root = Toplevel(root)
        Label(self.root, text="A2").pack(padx=20, pady=20)
```

this should solve you problem